# Can macros on excel run after refreshing data on a sheet from Hyperion Essbase?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, database

Trying to create a file that runs repetitive actions on its own with macros but was curious on limitations of what macros can't do, as in, are they not capable to run if you refresh data from an add-in software?

Comment: Why do you need refresh data? How do you refersh it? After refreshing if the data is updated, your requirment maybe avaliable. Please provide more information.

Comment: @Lee because it's data extracted from hyperion essbase that is updated on a monthly basis.

Comment: Macros can do a lot, but most times require tweaking if you want to generalize. For instance if the data set stays the same size a macro may work. But if the data set expands on each refresh then VBA (think of it as a generalized macro) is the way to go. With VBA you can even build the refresh into the process, so that everything you want can be done one time (click of a button or even on startup of spreadsheet). Hope this general comment helps.

Comment: @gns100 I think VBA would work with what I want to get done, however, I think VBA is too advanced for my capabilities. I have never written code for excel. what did you have in mind when you mentioned creating the process through VBA?

Comment: Sometimes when I want to automate a spreadsheet, I record a macro first. Then I look at the VBA that was created (recording a macro is excel writing VBA). I then modify that VBA to generalize (for example using a named range) and optimize (for example going to a specific cell instead of the page commands excel created).